# Pass function from grandparent to grandchild in React

Tags: reactjs

So I'm kinda new to React. Currently I have a web application that is getting kinda complex.
I'm bulding a mini dashboard. In this dashboard I have a Table component, that is built using several Rows (also components). Each one of this Rows have several MiniRows inside. In order to simulate a Table inside a Row.

Inside each one of my Mini rows I have a button that can delete that row. In order to do this, I need to call a function that is on the Table component (Grandparent).
What is the proper way to do this? I've searched about it and I want to avoid props drilling.
Should I try to learn to use something like Redux? Or is it too complicated?

My components are structured something like this in therms of hierarchy.

```
<Table/>
  <Row/>
    <MiniRow/>
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2):

You Might Not Need Redux, and certainly not for this.

If you want to avoid prop drilling, you could have the Table component set up a [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that the child and grandchild components are able to access.

Remember to properly memoize the value you pass to the `Context` to avoid unnecessary deep re-renders.